# D3 time scale bar chart is not align with x axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3.js and I created bar chart with timescale.

But the barchart is not aligned center with x axis.

date is set as this format.
*2018-04-01T00:00:00Z*

As you can see all the charts are left moved.

How can I fix this?
[error is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXUen.jpg)

Comment: Would you please show us some code so we can help you?

Comment: That's a common outcome when you use a time scale in a bar chart, which you shouldn't (use categorical scales instead). To see how to move the bars to the left, please have a look at the dupe target (the link below *"This question already has an answer here"*).